# What are the properties of a non ACID table in Apache Hive?

Tags: hive, acid

As of now, ACID properties in Apache Hive are only supported for the ORC file format. I have data in Parquet files (lets say they're very large). I want to figure out the pros and cons of leaving the data as is and using a non-ACID table vs converting the Parquet data to ORC (thus having to deal with 2 sets of data and keeping them in sync) and having ACID properties.
I wanted to understand which aspects of ACID exactly aren't offered if using a non-ACID table and what limitations it puts on my usage of that data.
Any links to further information would also help!

[This](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/hive+transactions) link tells me about the ACID properties that are guaranteed when using the ORC format. However, I can't find any information as to what would be the impact (ex - Do transactions in a non-ACID table not lock the data? Are certain operations not allowed? etc) if not using ACID.